# error: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3 (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm new to android and I build my first test project in android studio but get this error

Java compiler

```java
error: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
(use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
```

how should i fix it?

[image: This is the Error]

And this is my gradle

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Any luck on this? I am also having the same issue.

Comment: Please check if my answer works for you also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had the same issue, the problem was that my`sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` in `compileOptions` were pointing to `kotlin_version` set them to your correct java versions in your project level `build.gradle` file.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "x.y.z"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
}
```